# Transformar objeto em array mantendo o índice

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist, objetos, array-associativo

Boa tarde Amigos quem pode me ajudar?
Eu tenho esse Array de objetos, precisava transformar esse Objeto em lista mais mantendo o indice como está

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando o Map ele muda o indice:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisava depois acessar cada item para realizar cálculos porem o parâmetro de comparação é o índice.

Obraços

Comment: se for php usa json_decode($var, true);

Comment: Posta o código que é melhor.

Comment: Blza Leandro? Então cara tó fazendo um map var array = teste.map(el => Object.keys(el).map(key => el[key]));
                            console.log(array);

Comment: Willian é JavaScript, preciso acessar depois da seguinte forma: array[0].1024.0 para pegar o valor 0.0748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar da função [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
const original = {0: 0.08075, 1024.0: 51200.0}
const map = new Map(Object.entries(original));
console.log(map);
```

Comment: Opá, Valeu pedro, isso mesmo, porem ainda me retornou só array mais dessa forma já consigo trabalhar os dados. Obrigado